# React, Firebase Auth error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I have been getting this error when trying to authenticate using firebase with react.

I was able to log in after i updated all the Node_modules, but when i get the logged in user data from firebase i get this error code.

```
O {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "toJSON failed: First argument must be a valid string."}
```

I have been creating a file almost identical to this repo.

https://github.com/TaylorRayHoward/ReactReduxMessageBoard/tree/Video2

Even if i run this code, I'm unable to login and i still get the same error.

Comment: Did you change the rules `.read: true`, `.write: true`, if not click on the rules tab in firebase console and change it.

Comment: yeah both are set to true

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution...

When i was using the redux devtools with google chrome the error came up. Now when i have removed the code from my application, the error does not exist any more.